# Creating multiuser chatroom in XMPP client

Tags: command-line, google, google-talk, xmpp

I am using the Profanity XMPP client to create a multiuser chatroom in the terminal.

My understanding of the XMPP protocol is that when you join a chatroom with a new name like

/join NewChatRoom

it automatically creates the new chatroom. It doesn't do this for me, and I don't know why. I'm wondering if it has to do maybe with the default domain name the client assigns to the new chatroom, like NewChatRoom@conference.gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Profanity will append the domain as you showed if one is not supplied.  You can supply one if it is different from the default.

It will also only allow you to create a room if no room configuration is required.

For more information on the join command see: http://www.profanity.im/rooms.html

And room configuration is planned for a future release: https://github.com/boothj5/profanity/issues/169